# Remove padding of a certain section using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I've noticed there is a small amount of padding on one of my containers that i would like to remove entirely however the code i am implementing doesn't seem to be working.

**CSS:**

```
.elementor-container elementor-coloumn-gap-default {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

I think i may have the name of the element wrong. My website is [www.monoalarms.co.uk/wp](http://www.monoalarms.co.uk/wp) and i am trying to remove the padding from the container that contains that 5 buttons. it is directly under the header image.

Comment: what is `elementor-coloumn-gap-default` ? i think it should be a class so you are missing the className selector `.` - > `.elementor-coloumn-gap-default`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking padding in wrong container,
please try next css -

```
.elementor-column-gap-default>.elementor-row>.elementor-column>.elementor-element-populated { padding-bottom: 0; }
```

Seems your padding goes from banner

Comment: could you please explain what i was missing? the code works great, but i am having trouble visualising what you did to get this code.

Answer (score 0):

their could be many other css styles overriding yours. Remember CSS tries to take the last styling, so make sure yours is loaded last. You might need a more specific tag i.e 'body .elementor-container elementor-coloumn-gap-default', right click element and inspect in chrome, at the bottom of the browser you'll see the exact CSS tag it uses.